# Get Azure KeyVault secrets from On-Prem Server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

Scenario - I have an unix environment where I would like to fetch secrets for the azure KeyVault that is created

I understand, If we are using cloud related service in Azure, we can go with LinkedService and establish connection. But how can we do it via on-prem server?

I  dont want to use AzCLi since I am using via spark-shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python SDK to get the Azure Key Vault secrets

You can create a service principal and assign access policy to get the secrets for this service principal in your Key Vault

Then you can use the below sample code to fetch the Azure Key Vault secret:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

TENANT= <TenantId>
CLIENT_ID = <ClientId>
CLIENT_SECRET= <ClientSecret>
credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)

VAULT_URL= <AzureVault-url>
client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)

example_secret = client.get_secret(<secret_name>)
print(example_secret.value)
```